# Android ListView items too big dont know why

Tags: java, android, xml

I was testing my application and founded this bug.[This is how UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOX1m.jpg)

Running on Android 5.1 but in higher versions that does not happen... this is the full XML code
[XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en74t.jpg.)

Source code at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/rowTareaBackGround">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tituloTarea"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEliminarTarea"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/papelera"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Textview `android:layout_weight="4"` to  `android:layout_weight="1"`

and remove your `android:layout_weight="1"` from Button

Change your code according to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tituloTarea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnEliminarTarea"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEliminarTarea"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesnt work because the button needs a width. It's bad practice to give a size for the width. that's why I use it the weight on both items

Comment: Have you remove weight from button or not?

Comment: The thing you have tot do this only remove `weight` completely from **button** and make **TextView** `weight`=1 and make **textView** width match_parent also

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Because the button has 0dp width and the textview is match parent and you want to add weigth 1? Bad performance then...

Comment: please upload xml source code i will edit that and give you new code according to your desire

Comment: This is with your changes: https://gyazo.com/0f2869f8fe61ca665f73de82105f9b32

Comment: Please upload your source code It's too easy. I will make changes in your source code according to your desire

Comment: i gave you the full XML code, dont need more i think xd

Comment: please upload your in your question as text don't send me your code pic again and again

Comment: Dont work properly because the button appears to the right of the text and and I want it to show up on the right side of the layout xD

Comment: Ok! Got it you want button in another layout?

Comment: No xD in Android Studio yes but when I execute on my phone noup

Comment: please add your phone screen shot

Comment: As i know it's too easy but Don't know why it's taking too much time

Comment: Now i have update the code and as i know now, it will definately work 100%

Comment: Can you please accept my answer by clicking on tick button?